# How does Hadoop framework decides the node to run Map job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

As per my understanding, files stored in HDFS are divided into blocks and and each block is replicated to multiple nodes, 3 by default. How does Hadoop framework choose the node to run a map job, out of all the nodes on which a particular block is replicated.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there will be same amounts of `map` tasks as amounts of blocks.

See manual [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Mapper).

Usually, framework choose those nodes close to the input block for reducing network bandwidth for `map` task.

That's all I know.

Answer (score 0):

In Mapreduce 1 it depends on how many map task are running in that datanode which hosts a replica, because the number of map tasks is fixed in MR1. In MR2 there are no fixed slots, so it depends on number of tasks already running in that node.